# Pop over screen SKScene in game

Tags: xcode, swift

I created a game in Xcode with Swift in Sprite Kit. I am trying to have the ability to do the following. If the user presses a certain button I would like another screen that partially gets presented that has a swift file on it's own. Anyone has any idea how to do this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [`SKView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKView/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/SKView) is a subclass of [`UIView`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview) either can be added as a subview (see [addSubview](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622616-addsubview) and [insertSubview](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622598-insertsubview)) to the scene view depending on what you want to put in that view.

You can decide when and how to show the view, controlling its visibility by the [`UIView.isHidden`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622585-ishidden) property (which determines if the view even renders at all), or the use [`UIView.alpha`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622417-alpha) to fade it to any degree of invisibility, and also use the view's layer ([`UIView.layer.zPosition`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/calayer/1410884-zposition)) property top put it on top of the other views when you need it to appear or 'pop up'.